# Getting QgsGemetry.fromWkt to show up?

Tags: pyqgis

I am following a tutorial from "QGIS Python Programming Cookbook", and I am having some trouble, even with a near exact replication of the code, and I could use a second/third pair of eyes as to why I might not be getting the layer to show up on the map.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


app = QgsApplication([], True)
app.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\", True)
app.initQgis()
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
canvas.setWindowTitle("PyQGIS Standalone Application Example")
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs=epsg:4326', 'MyLine' , "memory")
if not layer.isValid():
   print "Layer Failed to load!"
pr = layer.dataProvider()
linstr = QgsFeature()
geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt("LINESTRING (1 1, 10 15, 40 35)")
linstr.setGeometry(geom)
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
canvas.setExtent(layer.extent())
canvas.setLayerSet([QgsMapCanvasLayer(layer)])
canvas.zoomToFullExtent()
canvas.freeze(True)
canvas.show()
canvas.refresh()
canvas.freeze(False)
canvas.repaint()
exitcode = app.exec_()
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
sys.exit(exitcode)
```

[image: No layer showing!! :(]

Comment: You are not adding the feature to the layer

Comment: I was always taught to place the import of pyqt librairies before qgis It can creates conflicts.

Comment: No you should import QGIS before Qt so you get the newer Qt API.

Comment: @NathanW, your first comment sounds like an answer.